# How to change UIButton title which placed in prototype cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have `TableView` with custom type of cells. In prototype `cell` I have 3 buttons. I want to be able change button title when I pressed on another. I trying this:

```
- (IBAction) doSomething:(id) sender { 

    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView]; 
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)hitIndex.row); //This works and I can see the row which button placed
    MyCustomViewCell *cell = [_myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithidentifier:@"myCell"];

    //I'm tried this:
    cell.button.titleLabel.text = @"111";

    //and I'm tried this:
    [cell.button setTitle:@"222" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     MyCustomViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

      cell.textLabel.text = _productNameForClearance;
      cell.imageView.image = _productImageForBasket;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If your button is type of UIButton you should use [cell.button setTitle:@"111" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Have you used the debugger to verify that your code gets the proper `indexPath` for the button and that `cell` is not `nil`?

Comment: I'm wrote above:   NSLog(@"%ld", (long)hitIndex.row); //This works and I can see the row which button placed

Comment: Where do `_productNameForClearance` and `_productImageForBasket` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is that this code gives you an entirely unrelated cell:

```
MyCustomViewCell *cell = [_myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithidentifier:@"myCell"];
```

It has the right class, so you can modify it without an error, but it is not the cell that is visible in your `UITableView`.

You should have some non-UI state that tells you what title to display, though: otherwise, scrolling a cell with the new title off the screen and back on will bring the old title back, which would be wrong.

To do what you are trying to achieve correctly, you need to implement the change in two places: first, the `doSomething` code should modify the model state responsible for changing the title, like this:

```
// This needs to be part of your model
NSMutableSet *rowsWithChangedTitle = ...

- (IBAction) doSomething:(id) sender { 

    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView]; 
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)hitIndex.row); //This works and I can see the row which button placed
    [myModel.rowsWithChangedTitle addObject:@(hitIndex.row) ];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Then, you would need to change your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomViewCell *cell = [_myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithidentifier:@"myCell"];
    ...
    if ([myModel.rowsWithChangedTitle containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]) {
            cell.button.titleLabel.text = @"111";
            [cell.button setTitle:@"222" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: all genius are simple isn't it )

Comment: myModel is not clear.i know what model is but how should i do it in code?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Is it possible to change the label text without reloading.

Comment: @Balaji Yes. Please ask a new question, someone will show the code explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add action handler that provides touch event to button in cell.
Like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* reuseIdentifier = [self cellReuseIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyCustomCell* cell = (MyCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonAction:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// your implementation

}
```

And here's `cellButtonAction:forEvent:` implementation:

```
- (IBAction)cellButtonAction:(id)sender forEvent:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];
    // your code here
    MyCustomCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    [cell.button setTitle:@"222" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is going to work initially, but once you scroll the cell off the screen and back on, the visual effect is going to disappear.

Comment: Yes, you should also save new button title to datasource, because cell objects are reused. That means once cell disappears from tableView it's content is might be replaced by content that is begin set in 'tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:'. So in 'tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:' you should also add something like:
'[cell.button setTitle:self.titlesDatasource[indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];'

Answer (score 0):

Replace line:

```
MyCustomViewCell *cell = [_myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithidentifier:@"myCell"];
```

with:

```
MyCustomViewCell *cell = [_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: hitIndex]
```

When you pressed the button the title is changed but when you scroll and the row with the changed title disappear the cell is recycled and when you scroll back the cell is taken from the recycled pool and is set up with initial values.
My advice is to create array where you keep track of your changed rows(titles) and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you should displayed the changed title from that array.

Comment: This is going to work initially, but once you scroll the cell off the screen and back on, the visual effect is going to disappear.

Comment: I thing because you use CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView]; Try replace CGPointZero with some point from your button (sender), for example UIButton * btn = (UIButton*)sender; btn.center; .

Comment: The reason this is not going to "stick" after being scrolled off is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns the current visual, which is a transient object by Cocoa's design, due to cell recycling. In order for the change to be permanent, there needs to be code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that performs the right changes on the cell, based on some persistent indicator that the OP does not have at the moment. There is no way to make it work without such indicator.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I dont undestand, now, when I'm scrolling - the title remains in place, it's have to disappear?

Comment: @user2987175 Yes, it needs to go off screen, so that the cell gets recycled.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if I understand all clear you said that this solution it's works but when I scroll the cell off the screen and back on, the visual effect is going to disappear - but it doesn't happend, when I scroll,  and back again title remains in place

Comment: Can you try replace your MyCustomViewCell *cell = ... with MyCustomViewCell *cell = (MyCustomViewCell*)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]; It doesn't look nice but I just want to see is it work.

Comment: @Greg, yes it's works ) And the title is remains in place, but some magic happend - im my tableView I sent 15 the same data, and when I pressed on the first row button, the title of button changes the current line and the line through three of her ) so why can occur?